# Exchange internal ip blindly using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, ip

I would like to share my internal IP between two devices on a network (using python 3).

Let's say I have my phone, and my computer. Both connected to the same network. I need to run a client and server script to connect the two but in order to do that, my phone (client) needs the ip of the computer (server).
The IP of the computer changes all the time (school wifi, nothing I can do about it) and even so I would like this to work instantly when connected to a new router without having to manually enter the IP.

One more thing, due to the huge amounts of devices on the network, mapping every device and finding the computer name to get the IP will take too long for its purpose.

Comment: Hi, first please notice that Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Second: Finding your device shouldn't be too hard if you lookup the ip-mac relations in a table created by the arp protocol. How that is done in python tho... no idea :/

Comment: I apologize if it seemed like I was asking for someone to write code. I simply want to know if there is a method of doing it. Maybe there is a special IP and port that one can use on all networks to communicate or something. Could you expand slightly on how and where "ip-mac relations in a table created by the arp protocol" work? I've run out of things to google.

Comment: You don't need to apologize, i just mentioned it because often times new users have expectations that are too high for this site. On topic: to find your device you need to an arp table. Those are lists of ip addresses and the respective mac address. In python you can get those tables via a library called 'python_arptable', installable with pip. Btw: if you want to google this in more detail search for 'address resolution protocol'.

Comment: I've done some more research and testing, and it seems that an arp table uses pre-discovered IP addresses, to get the mac address from the IP. And since I need this to work on new networks, this question will remain a mystery.

Comment: Eh. Not necessarily, the thing is that you would probably need to let your computer think it's a router for a moment to initialize the table by scanning the network ... thinking about it, maybe a brute force approach would be easier. Anyway: my point is that nothing remains a mystery if you're curious enough ;>

Comment: What you are describing is what multicast can be used for. Have the discoverable device subscribe to a particular multicast group, and have the discovering device send a discovery packet to the multicast group. The discoverable device can then respond with its unicast address. This is done all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone was wondering. I take this question as unsolvable, but, in order to solve my issue, I have set my computer to upload its internal IP to a server each time it connects to a new network. My phone then reads the server.

Comment: What you are describing is what multicast can be used for. Have the discoverable device subscribe to a particular multicast group, and have the discovering device send a discovery packet to the multicast group. The discoverable device can then respond with its unicast address. This is done all the time. Seriously, you really need to understand networking before trying to write network applications. That is why we have such vulnerablilities with network software; the programmer doesn't really understand the technology.

Comment: First, I would like to just clarify that this script is just for me, and although I know that it is insecure, I doubt anyone but an experienced hacker will be able to do much more than just read the communication (which is just some code words to run scripts on my computer, which again, aren't particularly powerful). Secondly, from my understanding of unicast from some research here: (https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/05/ip-multicasting/) I still require an IP address to start! Ultimately defeating the purpose.

Comment: Edit: I was wrong about the IP, I must have misread the information. Apparently, there exists a Multicast IP, which i must assume works on any network and is independent of internal IP.  I will do more research as to how to do it on python.

Comment: When you send to a predetermined multicast group, you do not need to know the receiving unicast address. The reply can include the unicast address. "_I doubt anyone but an experienced hacker will be able to do much more than just read the communication..._" Always, always assume that there is an experienced hacker on the network, even if it is just the network owner. Assume that _everything_ you do on someone else's network is transparent to the network owner, and at least one other person.

Comment: See, that is my point. You don't even know about multicast, a Network 101 subject. You can consider it a selective broadcast. Rather than interrupting _every_ host on the network to process a broadcast, it only interrupts the hosts tha have subscribed to a particular multicast group. You can register a multicast group with IANA, or you can use someing in the Administratively Scoped range (`239.0.0.0/8`).

Comment: Final answer: I have been successful by using this: (https://pymotw.com/2/socket/multicast.html) which is a multicast example as Ron Maupin suggested. I do want to clarify that I am just a 17-year-old kid, who is self-taught in python and is still in school and has therefore not taken a "network 101 subject". This was just meant to be a fun little project, and I do intend on actually learning about this stuff in university. In summary, thank you for suggesting to look into multicast, I will have to try it on my school wifi though because I fear that like many other things it will be blocked.

Comment: Multicast is not routed by default, but it works on the same network because it is sent at layer-2 using lsyer-2 MAC addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Please use DNS for the purpose, or assign static addresses to your devices, and use the defined static addresses in your scripts.

Comment: As I've stated, since it is not my wifi, I cannot set my IP address as static and I would also like this to work on different networks, using a DNS also requires me to enter the IP address.